# How did Hopper and Joyce leave the Upside Down?

Tags: stranger-things

In the Episode "Upside Down" Hopper and Joyce enter the Upside Down to find Will; we see they walk a lot and visit many locations, but we never come to see how they find the way back and leave the dark.

I see two possibilities:

1. they somehow tracked their movements and return to the same breach they used to enter;
2. they find a new breach, near where they are, maybe the one opened by the Demogorgon at the school (which seems to be its nest in the Upside Down).

Is there an official explanation for this, both in/out universe?

Comment: I just assumed they returned the way they came in. They seem to know the town well, so it wouldn't be a problem for them. That's just my two cents.

Comment: @n00dles That would be my assumption as well. Kids in the 80s were allowed to explore the world as much as they wanted, so there's no doubt they could've found their way back through the forest without much trouble.

Comment: “maybe the one opened by the Demogorgon at the school (which seems to be its nest in the Upside Down)” — I think the Demogorgon’s nest is in the library, not the school.